# Countdown timer showing wrong for the given date and time

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I am creating a simple countdown timer which takes difference from two dates and outputs it like: 01 day 23 hours 59 minutes

In PHP:

```
$this_is_old_date = 2020-06-08 13:52:18; // let's take it as tody date
$old_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this_is_old_date);
$expire = clone $old_date;
$expire->add(new DateInterval('P2D')); // add two days from today date
$exp = $expire->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Everything works fine

In javascript:

```
function getTimeRemaining(expire) {
    var t = Date.parse(expire) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

var expire = "<?php echo $exp; ?>";
getTimeRemaining(expire);
```

When I call this function `getTimeRemaining(expire)` it start with  **1 day 20 hours 30 minutes**, But my expected time is **01 day 23 hours 59 minutes** how to fix it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the source of a date that `expire` is created from? 3,5h of difference in returned value seems like there might be a time zone issue (for example: your local vs server/database/other client).

Comment: expire date is comes from $exp variable (var expire = "<?php echo $exp; ?>";).

Comment: is your question regarding the formatting (the missing 0 at the start) or the 3 hour difference?

Comment: my question regarding 3 hours difference

Comment: @karthik yes I can see that, sorry for the mental shortcut... where is `$this_is_old_date` coming from?

Comment: @cyborg86pl variable $this_is_old_date is comes from mysql. Which is actually date and time of product creation

Comment: @cyborg86pl And i also changed my timezone using DateTimeZone(); but still i have same issue

Comment: @karthik does my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try making all dates to the same timezone (to resolve the difference error as @cyborg86pl mentioned in the comments)

Do something like this.

**PHP:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC')

$this_is_old_date = 2020-06-08 13:52:18; // let's take it as tody date
$old_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this_is_old_date);
$expire = clone $old_date;
$expire->add(new DateInterval('P2D')); // add two days from today date
$exp = $expire->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function utcDate(date) {
    return new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds()));
}

function getTimeRemaining(expire) {
    var t = utcDate(new Date(Date.parse(expire))) - utcDate(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

var expire = "<?php echo $exp; ?>";
getTimeRemaining(expire);
```

Comment: @karthik https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
Here is API documentation.

Check what is the result of `Date.parse(expire)` it should be a proper date.
Or check this one `new Date(Date.parse(expire))`.